# Loop Foreach into WSO2ESB doesn't working

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I'm integrating wso2dss 3.5 and wso2esb 4.9. In DSS, I created a DataService to get data from a database. Following the WSO2 Dashboard into DSS, I used the endpoint in my eclipse project (Developer Studio). The xml gerated by DSS is:

```
<elements xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <row>
      <name>nome1</name>
      <address>rua xalala das xalalas</address>
   </row>
   <row>
      <name>nome2</name>
      <address>ruas rms did sa</address>
   </row>
   <row>
      <name>nome3</name>
      <address>aldoas daso dasodsa</address>
   </row>
</elements>
```

So, in my ESB project I have this gerated code:

```
<foreach expression="//elements/row">
    <sequence>
      <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <p:Insert xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <xs:nome xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:nome>
            <xs:endereco xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:endereco>
          </p:Insert>
        </format>
        <args>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="/row/name"/>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="/row/address"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
      <log>
        <property name="xalela" value="xalxalxlalxal"/>
      </log>
    </sequence>
  </foreach>
```

The problem is that it isn't loggin into foreach, in other words, it isn't accessing inside the foreach mediator. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath `//elements/row` return nothing because node "**elements**" belong to namespace http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice

try with `//ds:element/ds:row and` define **ds** as `xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"`

Comment: It is not working yet.. I changed my foreach to <foreach expression="//ds:element/ds:row" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
        <sequence>
          <log description="" level="full"/>
        </sequence>
      </foreach> and it is not logging..

Comment: In your comment above, you forget a 's' at the end of "elements" and verify if http:// is included inside your namespace declaration